# Avoid bundled files to be named index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, rollupjs

I’m using [vite](https://vitejs.dev) with React 17 and use [code splitting through the use of `import()`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import). I also use React’s [`lazy` function to lazy-load](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) my routes.

This gives something like that in my `App.jsx` main file (note that I use the [resolve.alias](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) feature of vite to avoid relative paths):

```js
const FourOFour = lazy(() => import('@/routes/four-o-four'))
const Home = lazy(() => import('@/routes/home'))
const Page1 = lazy(() => import('@/routes/page1'))
const Page2 = lazy(() => import('@/routes/page2'))
const Page3 = lazy(() => import('@/routes/page3'))
const Page4 = lazy(() => import('@/routes/page4'))
```

I have a file architecture like this:

```
src/components
├── alert
│   ├── alert.jsx
│   ├── alert.module.css
│   └── index.js
├── card
│   ├── card.jsx
│   ├── card.module.css
│   └── index.js
└── input-button
    ├── index.js
    ├── input-button.jsx
    └── input-button.module.css
```

Whenever I want to import a component, I do it like this:

```js
import Alert from '@/components/alert'
```

Everything is working fine but I noticed that when I build my app, I end up with several `index-[hash].js` files in the `dist/assets` directory… And I don’t really like that:

```
dist/assets
├── alert.29eaae95.js
├── alert.9d071fcb.css
├── four-o-four.59d2db8c.js
├── index.0a2941c6.js
├── index.0c141fac.js
├── index.1bf7b1e4.js
├── index.474a5715.css
├── index.52068596.css
├── index.5375aa61.js
├── index.560b62ee.js
├── index.574d7540.css
├── index.75008c1d.js
├── index.757602c4.css
├── index.79d989af.css
├── index.8e37fca8.js
├── index.de2d957e.js
├── index.ef72e18b.css
├── last.eb6ae9c9.js
├── logo.220bf9df.svg
├── notify.0d36b9fb.js
└── uniqBy.024d0774.js
```

I tried playing with `rollupOptions.output.chunkFileNames` but that doesn’t feel right…

```js
export default {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
          if (chunkInfo.facadeModuleId) {
            const splitPath = chunkInfo.facadeModuleId.split('/')
            const [fileName] = splitPath.splice(-1, 1)
            const [dirName] = splitPath.splice(-1, 1)

            if (fileName === 'index.js') {
              return `assets/${dirName}-[hash].js`
            }
          } else if (chunkInfo.name === 'index') {
            return `assets/[hash].js`
          }

          return 'assets/[name]-[hash].js'
        },
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          const splitPath = assetInfo.name.split('/')
          const [fileName] = splitPath.splice(-1, 1)
          const [dirName] = splitPath.splice(-1, 1)

          if (dirName && /^index\.\S+$/.test(fileName)) {
            return `assets/${dirName}-[hash][extname]`
          }

          return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]'
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Side note: this question was also posted in [vite’s repository discussions](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/9515) a few days ago but didn’t get any replies (yet), hence this SO post.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no cleaner way to get what you want. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4858) to get updates.